# error when installing angular-ide, getting operation not permitted error ,tried with root user

Tags: npm, npm-install

```
<pre>fs.js:114
    throw err;
    ^
```

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, chmod '/usr/lib/node_modules/angular-ide/bin/ng'
        at Object.chmodSync (fs.js:1027:3)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/angular-ide/scripts/post.js:6:4)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
        at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
        at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
        at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/angular-ide/node_modules/fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

Answer (score 0):

I find this in your uploaded error **Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})**
Did you try to solve this.

Comment: the error came because of **error throw in fs.js** file which is inbuilt file, it was not related to OS?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest to install a node version manager as it can help you to prevent a lot of problems regarding permissions (which seems to be your problem), more info see [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm#using-a-node-version-manager-to-install-nodejs-and-npm), as you are running Linux, the version manager that you probably want to use is [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).

Cheers!